# Can I paste a yanked line even if I delete a line?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, register

When I yank a line with `y` and paste it with `p`, it's okay. But when I need to delete a line with `dd` before pasting my yank buffer changes. Can I still paste my yanked line? Is there a way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way could be to overwrite that line instead of deleting it:

1. Copy the content
2. Move to line to be deleted and press `V` to select the whole line (or use `v` and manually select whichever region you need)
3. Press `p` to paste.

Comment: This is also a good solution. The other question, which this is a duplicate of, has nice answers too.

Comment: Yes, and mine doesn't quite fit there, that's why I answered here. :)

Comment: Thanks. But I think you should add this answer to there too, because this question will be closed as a duplicate most probably. I think yours is a good alternative solution.

Comment: @purplehuman Closed questions will remain on the site, and can still be voted & commented on. The only thing you *can't* do is add new answers.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Ah, okay. Good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Yanked text is kept in register `"0` until the next explicit yank. This means that you can cut as many lines as you want, `"0p` will still put the same text.

Another option is to use the black hole register, `"_` to actually delete text instead of the default "cut" behavior. This will preserve the unnamed register and let you `p` from it as much as you want.

See `:help registers`.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I'm out of votes for 2 hours. :) I'll be back.

Comment: All already listed in http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/125/205.

Comment: Yeah, that site and its questions are a joke.