# do a command without altering the register

Tags: cut-copy-paste, register

Sometimes I delete a line and when I want to yank it somewhere else I found out that I need to delete another line.
How can I delete the new line without overriding the the content of the line that I deleted before in the register ?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker dang you beat me to it by seconds! :D OP: also try: http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/710/can-i-paste-a-yanked-line-even-if-i-delete-a-line/711#711