# How to copy paste one value and overwrite another

Tags: vimrc, cut-copy-paste

A common function I do in textmate or any other editor is copy some text and then paste it over some other text, for example: https://gyazo.com/fcef05504e83b608b583af085f92ecd2.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Currently to copy a value I do something like `yiw`, however if I delete the next work, `diw`, it would also yank in that text, which I want to overwrite. What would be the best way to do this process, which I feel like I do all the time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Performing certain operations without clearing register](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/122/performing-certain-operations-without-clearing-register)

Comment: @Biggybi I don't think that one is a great duplicate for this one, since the way it's phrased doesn't lead to the `p` in Visual mode solution same as this one does... It's related and some solutions from that one will also work for this one, but I still think this one has a nice specific solution, so worth keeping it open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest is probably to select the word to be replaced in visual mode instead of deleting it:

```
viwp
```

If you don’t like that, an alternative is to delete without clobbering your yanked text by deleting into the black hole register:

```
"_diwp
```

Another alternative is to delete normally, but then paste from the yank register, which isn’t overwritten by your delete:

```
diw"0p
```

See [`:help registers`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#registers) for more details on the above.