# Stop the normal mode delete commands from copying text

Tags: cut-copy-paste

When editing text, I find it quite irritating that the normal mode commands, `x`, `d` and `s` all copy the text they remove. Don't we have `y` for copying? Perhaps I am "just doing it wrong", but for example in the following snippet,

```
copy me

_____ here ____
```

I would `gg 0 yy jj fh dw h p`. But `dw` also copies the word so we end up where we started. Instead I do something like `gg 0 yy jj f<Space> p l de`. Same number of commands but feels awkward.

To be clear, I'm not asking for a more effective way of achieving the above copy/paste situation (but feel free include anyway). Rather, is it possible to have `d` to only delete text and not copy it?

Comment: Check this [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/122/performing-certain-operations-without-clearing-register/125#125).  I suggest you get used to it.  You can always use `quote0` to get the copid text. I would do the copy  by `Scopy<c-x><c-l>` or `dd:1t.<cr>`.

Comment: Also check this [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3329/5017).

Comment: Thanks. Yes I forgot I could paste on top of a visual selection..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim has many registers, and it's a shame not to use them all.

When you yank (copy) some text, it goes to the register "0". When you delete some word(s) they go to the register "-", when you delete some line(s) they go to the registers "1" (and old register "1" goes to register "2" and so on upto "9").

The problem arises when you put (paste) your text back. As Vim can't know what you exactly think of, it simply takes the last register used, be it "0", or "-", or "1"  (well, actually there are also "letter"-registers and such, but let's forget about them for a moment). So this is what we call "unnamed register".

So it is a very reasonable default. But if it's not want you really want, you have to specify `"0` (most often), `"1` or `"-` before `p` explicitly. That's all.

Comment: @algae Read `:h registers`. All "delete"-like commands are the same in this aspect. No real difference between `d`, `c`, `r`, `x` and so on. (Except, `x` can only delete lines in Visual mode, and such).